# Check of a nominaly pinned steel joint

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

I am interested how to check a nominally pined joint. Especially how to check its rotational capacity and whether i can define it as nominally pinned in structural fem model. I understand that there are criteria for nominally p. Joints but also there is a criterium that this joint must have enough of rotational capacity to accept rotation of the member.

I give an example.

Lets say i designed a nominally pinned joint according to eurocode criteria. Ran a calculation and got design forces. (shear force and maybe axial force). Joint satisfied all code checks but now i want to if this joint has rotational capacity to accept members end rotation (also calculated).

I know that there certain amount of estimation and engineering experience. But i would like to know what would do an experienced engineer when designing a joint that has stiffness somewhere between pinned and semirigid. And dont want to define it as semirigid in structural calculation.

Thank you

Comment: It should always be assumed that the "worst case" loading will be experienced. If this element were assumed to be fully pinned (no moment transfer) would that result in a safer design than a fully fixed condition?  In the real world, we cannot always tell if a foundation is actually rigid, so assume otherwise.  Paper engineering is no substitute for experience.

Comment: I understand that for member check is usually safer to consider joints as pinned. But i am wondering how to check this pinned connection. Especially how to check its rotational capacity and if this is an appropriate approach.